# Delphi - How to get substring from PAnsiChar?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How to get a substring from a string or stream pointed by a PAnsiChar? Copy command's document says it does not work well with pointers. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Copy

Comment: If you refer to this: *if the elements of the array are pointers or objects, these are not copied as well* it doesn't apply as the characters of the string that your `PAnsiChar` is pointing at, are not pointers. Please clarify if this is not what you refer to.

Comment: Lazy way is to convert to string and then use Copy. A bit inefficient but is that a problem for you?

Comment: Hi Tom, the string does not contain pointers. But copy expects first parameter as string. So, if we pass it a PAnsiChar, it will implicitly convert it to string. And if PAnsiChar points to extended ansi or utf8 character, then substring will be wrong.

Comment: How so? In Delphi-7? How will the substring be wrong?

Comment: Hello Tom and David, I will be back on the discussion soon. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: FWIW, the comment about pointers is for dynamic arrays which contain pointers. It does not apply to strings. As others have said, if you pass a PChar, PAnsiChar or PWideChar, these will be converted to strings first.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SetString](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_SetString.html) procedure.

If you want to copy a piece from the middle, just use pointer to needed beginning like this:

```
SetString(s, PAnsiChar(@p[3]), 2);
```

Note that you can use Copy - PChar will be implicitly transformed to string

```
var
  s: string;
  p: Pchar;
begin
  p := '12345';
  s := Copy(p, 1, 3);
  Caption := s;
```

Comment: This runs the risk of buffer overrun

Comment: @David Heffernan  Just noticed that my second example doesn't uses Copy (as stated). Or you mean something else?

Comment: No, the first example can overrun

Comment: @David: in what way a buffer overrun? AFAIK, `S` is set to length `Len` (i.e. 2 in this case) and then 2 `AnsiChars` are copied to `S`. This assumes that `S` is not a `ShortString`. Of course the address `@p[3]`(or `p + 3`) must be valid, otherwise you risk a read error. But I don't see a buffer overrun.

Comment: @David  SetString is not so high-level function as Copy with internal checks and might raise exception with too long copy-length. But caring about this problem is work for programmer's head, so I don't see a real problem

Comment: @Rudy When you are handed a null terminated character array, you don't know how long it is. So if it isn't as long as you hope, you may read off the end of the array.

Comment: @David: Ah, yes, a **read** error (e.g. an AV or whatever it is called, "page fault". etc.) as I said, but that is, IMO, not a buffer overrun. A buffer overrun or overflow is **writing** beyond the boundaries of a buffer. The string buffer is not overrun.

Comment: @Rudy I can agree that if you want to define that as not being a buffer overrun then you are correct. I was referring to the definition of buffer overrun used by the rest of the programming world. For instance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717795(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I was referring to the Wikipedia definition for [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow): "In computer security and programming, a buffer overflow, or buffer overrun, is an anomaly where a program, while **writing** data to a buffer, overruns the buffer's boundary and **overwrites** adjacent memory locations." (emphasis mine). So I really doubt your "rest of the programming world". But even your link says: "A static buffer overrun occurs when a buffer, which has been declared on the stack, is **written to** with more data than it was allocated to hold."

Comment: @David: In other words: a buffer overrun does not refer to **reading** from a buffer, it refers to overrunning or overflowing it (**writing** over the boundaries). SetString does not do that.

Comment: @rudy No. Overflow is not the same as overrun. You are quite the most incorrigible person.

Comment: @David: yes it is. Both mean writing over the boundaries of the buffer. See the link **you** posted: "A static buffer **overrun** occurs when a buffer, which has been declared on the stack, is **written to** with more data than it was allocated to hold." And that is, AFAIK, how the "rest of the programming world" sees it.

Comment: @rudy No, overflow does not mean the same as overrun. At least not in my understanding of the English language. But perhaps your English is better than mine.

Comment: @David: yes, it does, in this context. Both will lead to **overwriting** the memory beyond the boundaries of the buffer. That is why it is called *over*-**run**. But hey, you can have your own definition, if you like.

Comment: No. Overrun means to access beyond the end of the buffer. That can be read or write. Both have serious potential implications. It wouldn't take much research on your part to see how buffer overrun is used widely for buffer over read. But you aren't interested in what anybody else thinks. Anyone that disagrees with you is clearly wrong.